# URL shortener which does not follow hyperlinks

Tags: hosted, url-shortening

I need a URL shortener, which does not automatically go to the URL I provided.

The reason is that I am using a quizzing software, which generates a new user each time someone follows a link. So, when I shorten the URL for the session with common shorteners, I get one-two people generated simply from the shortener service checking the URL.

Is there some alternative that shortens the link without looking the page up?